# How many pages can be uploaded in the single website without offending popular search engines?

Tags: html, search-engines, database

Currently we are serving details to our visitors through a database oriented website. Visitor selects around 5 Level options

E.g. Level One: book
     Level Two: Chapter
     Level Three: Topic

Now we want to convert all the details in pure html contents so there will be around 20000 pages. (Our purpose of doing this is that the search engines will be able to crawl all the contents.)

If we convert Database contents into html pages and upload them all to our website in a single stroke, will there be any problem with popular search engines like google and yahoo?

Comment: Whether search engines are able to crawl your site, has nothing to with how the contents are stored. If you have a website the contents will always be displayed as HTML (or are not understood by any text based client, like a search engine spider). So what is the difference to your old way. How do you come to the idea, that there must be some limit in the number of pages linked on some website?

Comment: @feeela Contents are stored in database and it is displayed only after the visitor provides some criteria thorough selecting from UI combo-boxes, a select query fetches data from the database and then displays it to visitor. How search engine will be able to go through the database and index it? That is the reason I thought all the pages should be in stored/hosted as independent html file which will help the search engine to crawl the contents.

Comment: How do your user select something from which combo-box? How do your users see the data? You are not telling me, that phpMyAdmin is your current data access, did you? I guess you already have some sort of HTML output to present the data to your users.

Comment: @feeela Please go through the link: http://www.litebible.com/readbible.php?id=1 My question was inspired by this web site.

Comment: No, I wont. I you want some help, you really should come up with a answerable, complete question describing what you have done so far and where your problem is.

Comment: feeela is correct on 2 accords, 1: There is some eventual "crawled" potion of your site - what is that? 2: Figure out what you are doing first then ask us how we can improve on it. @feela - well said and well put.

Comment: @feeela  The data stored in database table: biblename bnumber bname cnumber VERS vnumber   For each language (E.g. English, Greek, Hindi, Gujarati etc.) there is one database table.  The html pages are build from database after fetching from table depending upon visitor criteria given from UI. Should we keep the database or should we pre-build all the pages in html format and host them  to server and remove the database? What is beneficial in terms of SEO?

Comment: @Brandt Solovij Please view my comment to feeela.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If we convert Database contents into html pages and upload them all to our website in a single stroke, will there be any problem with popular search engines like google and yahoo?

Assuming each of the pages is unique and has quality content, then no.  You won't have any "problems" with the engines but Google and Bing may not be able to find all of the pages unless you also publish a sitemap that directs the spider to the URLs.  Even if you get them to spider the contents, if the pages are not considered sufficiently different from each other or if Google determines them to be low-quality and search engine spambait then you may suffer some adverse consequences.

Answer (score 1):

Google and Bing does not bother whether your site is fetching data from a database or it is a HTML page.

Simply make a sitemap of your site and you are ready to go. Popular CMS like Wordpress, Joomla and Drupal fetch data from MySql database and still these CMS consider very good for SEO .

**All you need is a sitemap.**

See here to know what Google says about sitemap.

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156184